# Remote access to ArangoDB through Java Interface

Tags: java, arangodb

I have developed a Java application that uses ArangoDB as backend database (Used ArangoDB Java-Driver/Interface to access ArangoDB).

Everything is good until my ArangoDB and Application resides on same machine.

Once i moved ArangoDB to remote machine(Dedicated Server), my application is unable to access it :(

I have given my remote machine details(ArangoDB Server) in some properties file and feeding that file location to ArangoConfigure Constructor while creating ArangoDriver Object. But still i'm unable to access ArangoDB :(

Small snippet of my code is below:

```
protected static ArangoConfigure getConfiguration() {
        //ArangoConfigure configure = new ArangoConfigure();
        ArangoConfigure configure = new
ArangoConfigure("/Volumes/Official/ZLabs/arangodb.properties");
                configure.init();

        return configure;   }

    protected static ArangoDriver getArangoDriver(ArangoConfigure
configuration) {        return new ArangoDriver(configuration);     }
```

Please help me in this regard.

Awaiting your response.

Thanks & Best Regards,
- Mahi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Aranngodb Java driver fails to open or parse `/Volumes/Official/ZLabs/arangodb.properties` it issues a log message.

If arangodb properties looks like that:

```
port=8529
host=192.168.22.17
user=root
password=OpenSesame
enableCURLLogger=false
```

You start [walking up the OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) to debug TCP connection problems to evade possible connection issues due to firewals, routing etc.
One uses the commonly available telnet command to test the availability of the server:

```
telnet 192.168.22.17 8529
Trying 192.168.22.17...
```

If it sits there forever, you most probably have a firewall filtering you away, you finaly will get:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

If it immediately exits with:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

It seems the server doesn't answer.

On the server side you then can check whether the service has bound the port (8529) you're trying to connect:

```
netstat -alpnt |grep 8529
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8529            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19912/arangod
```

If you instead see it binding `127.0.0.1:8529` you won't be able to connect it remotely and need to change arangod.conf like this:

```
[server]
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529
```

And then restart ArangoDB. Then, you should be able to see something like this:

```
telnet 192.168.22.17 8529
Trying 192.168.22.17...
Connected to 192.168.22.17.
Escape character is '^]'. <start to type now: >
GET / HTTP/1.0

<server should reply:>
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html
Content-Type: text/html
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 197

<html><head><title>Moved</title></head><body><h1>Moved</h1>
<p>This page has moved to <a href="/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html">/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html</a>.
</p></body></html>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all thank you @dothebart for all your help.

@dothebart, I have checked all the details that you have mentioned, before i posted here. Only thing is missed is HTTP connectivity thanks for pointing that.

Actually the below code change has fixed the problem for me.

**Earlier code:**

```
ArangoConfigure configure = new ArangoConfigure("/home/arango.properties");
configure.init();
ArangoDriver driver = new ArangoDriver(configuration);
```

**Modified Code:**

```
ArangoConfigure configure = new ArangoConfigure("/home/arango.properties");
ArangoHost hostObj = new ArangoHost(<IP-Address>, 8529);
configure.setArangoHost(hostObj);
configure.setUser(<user-name>);
configure.setPassword(<password>);
configure.init();
ArangoDriver driver = new ArangoDriver(configuration);
```

Setting up of host, username and password again is making it to work :(

File has all the details, then why should i provide them again.. I didn't understand that.

@dothebart i'm unable to find the log file, please let me know where can i find it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the properties-file isn't found in the classpath.

The path of the log-file should be configured in your log-configuration-file in your project.
Your project may use for example [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) (logback.xml) or another [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) implementation.